# Overwrite anonymous struct function

Tags: go

How can I overwrite anonymous struct function.

To clarify what I mean look at the following code snippet:

```
package base

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Executer interface {
    Execute()
}

type Controller struct { }

func (self *Controller) Execute() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Controller")
}

func (self *Controller) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    self.Execute()
}
```

Now I am embedding the Controller struct into Test struct, also called anonymous

```
package base

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

type Test struct {
    Controller
}

func (self *Test) Execute() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Test")
}

func TestInheritance(t *testing.T) {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(&Test{})
    defer ts.Close()
    http.Get(ts.URL)
}
```

As output I've got "Hello Controller" but expected "Hello Test". You can see code above, I reimplement the execute function, but it does not work.

Comment: If you're trying to stub out or exchange the `Executer` functionality then you're doing it backwards. Embed (or otherwise include) an `Executer` into the `Controller` (perhaps have it use a `defaultExecute` type or somesuch unless told otherwise) and then give it a `stubExecute`/`testExecute`/whatever implementation of `Executer` for testing. Go is not Java, Go is not C++. An example of this type of thing is how the `net/http` package uses `DefaultClient`, `DefaultServeMux`, `DefaultTransport`, etc but you can supply your own too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Test` has no `ServeHTTP` method, your test server uses `Controller`'s, which calls `Controller.Execute()`. If you want it to work properly, define `ServeHTTP` for the `Test` type.

Comment: Golang does not support abstract method? So I have to reimplement ServeHTTP everytime? Test do have ServeHTTP method, it is inherit from Controller

Comment: No, go does not have abstract methods. There is also no inheritance, just delegation. You're calling `Controller.ServeHTTP`

Comment: @zero_coding If you want to be efficient with Go, you need to **stop** thinking with C++/Java OOP terms. Go is a language of *composition*. Your `Test` doesn't have a `ServeHTTP` so it delegates it to its part, the `Controller`. If you don't want it to delegate this, define `Test`'s own method.

Comment: So go language is not efficient in section polymorphie like java?

Comment: So I have to reimplement ServeHTTP everytime when I borrow fields from Controller?

Comment: Every time you need a behaviour that is different from `Controller`'s. Otherwise, delegation takes place.

Comment: @zero_coding: the fact you're still asking if go has abstract methods or Java's polymorphism shows you haven't taken the time to actually learn Go. Translating Java to Go just isn't going to work very well.

Answer (score -1):

```
type Test struct {
    Controller
}
```

`Controller` has no `ServeHTTP` method but `*Controller` has. So

```
type Test struct {
    *Controller
}
```

I think it will work.